# PeriodicTask and OneoffTask after migration from GCM to FCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Question**

What should I use in place of PeriodicTask and OneOffTask when migrating from GCM to FCM? Is there any equivalent in FCM packages?

**Background**

Recently Google has deprecated GCM and they provided [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm), but I couldn't find any informations there about migrating PeriodicTasks and OneOffTasks.

The tutorial says to [replace](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#switch-to-fcm-in-the-app-level-buildgradle) `play-services-gcm` with `firebase-messaging` but I couldn't find anything similar to the tasks inside this [package](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/package-summary), so I wonder if they completely resigned from them or if actually we can keep on using PeriodicTask/OneOffTasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PeriodicTask and OneoffTask classes (part of the GcmNetworkManager component) can be replaced with the [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), which is an open source library for scheduling units of work that will be executed in your app's process. The service-side API it exposes mirrors the framework's JobScheduler API, which is slightly different from the GcmNetworkManager. Upgrading should be a fairly easy, mechanical change.

### Upgrade steps

Add the following to your `build.gradle`'s dependencies section:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

Make your `GcmTaskService` implementations extend `JobService` instead. From this:

```java
public class MyTaskService extends GcmTaskService {
  @Override
  public int onRunTask(TaskParams params) {
    // Runs in its own thread
    // ...
    return RESULT_SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

To this:

```java
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
  @Override
  public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    // Runs on the main thread!
    // ...
    return false; // "Did we start any background work?"
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    // Runs on the main thread!
    // ...
    return false; // "Should this job be retried?"
  }
}
```

If you don't want to manage your own threading, you can take advantage of the `SimpleJobService` that comes with the library:

```java
public class MyJobService extends SimpleJobService {
  @Override
  public int onRunJob(JobParameters job) {
    // Runs on its own thread!
    // ...
    return JobService.RESULT_SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Make sure you adjust your manifest. Replace your previous `GcmTaskService` entry with something like this:

```
<service
    android:exported="false"
    android:name=".MyJobService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Scheduling is simple:

```java
// Create a new dispatcher using the Google Play driver.
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher =
  new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    // the JobService that will be called
    .setService(MyJobService.class)
    // uniquely identifies the job
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")
    // one-off job (only runs once unless a retry is requested)
    .setRecurring(false)
    // don't persist past a device reboot (requires RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE)
    .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
    // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
    // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
    .setReplaceCurrent(false)
    // retry with exponential backoff
    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
    // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
    .setConstraints(
        // only run on an unmetered network
        Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
        // only run when the device is charging
        Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
    )
    .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
    .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Check the [repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I noticed this library uses some constants with GCM in name eg. `com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_SCHEDULE`, shouldn't we be concerned about that?

Comment: Since Google announced yesterday [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), which uses Firebase JobDispatcher I take it as answer to my comment is "No" and thus JobDispatcher can be used. In fact, we should now probably consider using WorkManager instead of it.